# Why am I unable to update Listbox's RowSource property using excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

What my userform looks like with the properties window:
[image: Userform]

This is my code:

```
With Worksheets("List of Accounts").ListObjects("ListofAccounts").ListColumns(1).Range
    Total_rows_Accounts = .Find(What:="*", _
    After:=.Cells(1), _
    Lookat:=xlPart, _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
    MatchCase:=False).Row
End With

If Total_rows_Accounts > 1 Then
    lbxCurrent.RowSource = "List of Accounts!A2:A4"
End If
```

What my worksheet looks like:

[image: List of Accounts]

The error:

[image: Error]

Comment: @Tom That sounds like an answer

Comment: @QHarr Have updated

Comment: @Tom Thanks.. I never knew you needed to add apostrophe's to the range if it has spaces.

Comment: @MarcSantos not only to ranges. Basically any textfield / name that you're trying to reference that has spaces in it should be put inside apostrophes! *(This applies to almost all the programming languages, not only vba)*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your Range is incorrect. It should be `lbxCurrent.RowSource = "'List of Accounts'!A2:A4"` You're getting the error due to spaces in your sheet name